# Copy to Clipboard using Chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When I have the code and test it in my chrome it doesn't work in my local client.

What am I missing?

```js
function copyToClipboard( text ){
                var copyDiv = document.createElement('div');
                copyDiv.contentEditable = true;
                document.body.appendChild(copyDiv);
                copyDiv.innerHTML = text;
                copyDiv.unselectable = "off";
                copyDiv.focus();
                document.execCommand('SelectAll');
                document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
                document.body.removeChild(copyDiv);
            }
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="copyToClipboard('testtestt')" >
```

Thanks!

http://www.pakzilla.com/2012/03/20/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-chrome-extension/

"https://jsfiddle.net/wz28pp9k/3/"

Comment: If you don't wrap js code in onload method in jsFiddle, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/wz28pp9k/4/  Next time, debug your code...

Comment: Load script in `Head` https://jsfiddle.net/wz28pp9k/5/ is working.

Comment: it doens't work in my client computer. I also have acticated cognito in chrome but the same problem occur. "jsfiddle.net/wz28pp9k/5" Where can I retrieve the value to display it as a alert message for testing?

Comment: Wolff - It doesn't work in my client computer and I don't understand why

Comment: But how do you debug it??? Error in console? `Where can I retrieve the value to display it as a alert message for testing?` AFAIK this is not possible to get clipboard data outside any onpaste event. But anyway, in your provided example, you already know the data set in clipboard so your question doesn't really make sense. This is more relevant example to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/wz28pp9k/10/

Comment: Using Chrome Ctrl F12 and debugging it. I can see the process of the sorucecode but I cannot retrieve the result by pasting the value to display "testtestt".

Comment: How should I wrap up the code inside of the onlead method. Can you show me Wolff?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is many many ways.... e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/bm1o9o38/  Now i'm not sure this is your question because this is really basic example of js behaviour. What exactly are you expecting???

Comment: I tried a new approach by connecting to a remote desktop and the sourcecode works perfectly. thank you guys for your help!